# Fatal error SQLSTATE[42000]

Tags: php, mysql, sql, pdo

```
Fatal error: Uncaught PDOException: SQLSTATE[42000]: 
 Syntax error or access violation: 1064 You have an error in your SQL syntax;
 check the manual that corresponds to your MySQL server version for the right
 syntax to use near 'WHERE id_categoria = ? LIMIT ?, ?' at line 1 in
 /home2/odont919/app.odontobr.com/post.php:55 Stack trace: 
   #0 /home2/odont919/app.odontobr.com/post.php(55): PDO->prepare('SELECT * FROM p...') 
   #1 {main} thrown in /home2/odont919/app.odontobr.com/post.php on line 55
```

Esse erro aconteceu após alterar a ordem `SELECT * FROM post` para `SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC`. Alguém pode me ajudar por favor?

```
<?php
session_start();
require_once '_header.php';
require_once '_database.php';

if (!empty($_GET['act']) && $_GET['act'] == 'logout') {
    unset($_SESSION["id"]);
    header('location:index.php');
    exit();
}

$arr_cat[] = array();
$records = $conn->prepare('SELECT * FROM categoria order by nome');
if ($records->execute()) {
    $arr_cat = $records->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);
}

$_POST['paginaAtual'] = !empty($_POST['paginaAtual']) ? trim($_POST['paginaAtual']) : 1;
$_POST['qtdeItensPagina'] = !empty($_POST['qtdeItensPagina'])  ? $_POST['qtdeItensPagina']  : 40;

// always initialize a variable before use!
$conditions = array();
$parameters = array();

// conditional statements
if (!empty($_POST['legenda']))
{
    // here we are using LIKE with wildcard search
    // use it ONLY if really need it
    $conditions[] = 'legenda LIKE ?';
    $parameters[] = '%'.$_POST['legenda']."%";
}else $_POST['legenda'] = '';

if (!empty($_POST['id_categoria']))
{
    // here we are using equality
    $conditions[] = 'id_categoria = ?';
    $parameters[] = $_POST['id_categoria'];
}else $_POST['id_categoria'] = 0;

// the main query
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";

// a smart code to add all conditions, if any
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}

$parameters[] = ($_POST['paginaAtual'] - 1) * $_POST['qtdeItensPagina'];
$parameters[] = $_POST['qtdeItensPagina'];
$sql_post = $sql . " LIMIT ?, ?";

// the usual prepare/execute/fetch routine
$stmt = $conn->prepare($sql_post);
$stmt->execute($parameters);
$arr_post = $stmt->fetchAll(PDO::FETCH_ASSOC);

$stmt_qtde = $conn->prepare($sql);
$stmt_qtde->execute($parameters);
$vet = $stmt_qtde->fetch( PDO::FETCH_ASSOC );
$qtdeTotal = (int)$vet['qtde'];

?>
<main role="main">
  <section class="shadow-md p-3 bg-white rounded">
    <div class="container">
    <form method="post">
      <div class="form-row align-items-center">
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-8 ">
        <input type="text" name="legenda" value="<?=$_POST['legenda']?>" class="form-control" placeholder="Busque por um assunto ou hashtag...">
      </div>
      <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3 ">
        <select class="custom-select" name="id_categoria">
          <option value="0">Todas categorias...</option>
          <?php foreach ($arr_cat as $row) {?>
              <option <?=$row['id'] == $_POST['id_categoria'] ? 'selected' : ''?> value="<?=$row['id'];?>"><?=$row['nome'];?></option>
          <?php }?>
        </select>
       </div>
        <button type="submit" class=" col-sm-12 col-md-1 btn btn-primary"><i class="fas fa-search"></i></button>
      </div>
      <input type="hidden" name="paginaAtual" value="<?=$_POST['paginaAtual']?>" />
      </form>
  </section>

  <div class="album py-5">
    <div class="container">

        <?php if (count($arr_post) > 0) { ?>
            <div class="row">
                <?php foreach ($arr_post as $row) {?>
                  <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-3">
                      <div class="card mb-4 shadow-sm">
                        <img class="card-img-top" src="<?=$file_path . $row['nome_file']?>">

                        <div class="card-body">
                          <div class="card-title"><h6><?=$row['nome']?></h6></div>

                          <div class="d-flex justify-content-between align-items-center">
                            <div class="btn-group">
                                <?php if(!$limite_alcancado){?>
                                    <a data-toggle="tooltip" title="Ao pressionar download, será copiado a legenda para área de transferência" data-text="<?=$row['legenda']?>" target="_blank" href="_download.php?q=<?=base64_encode($row['id'].$separador.$row['nome'])?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-primary btn_legend"><i class="fas fa-download"></i> Download</a>
                                    <a href="detalhe.php?q=<?=base64_encode($row['id'].$separador.$row['nome'])?>" class="btn btn-sm btn-outline-secondary"><i class="fas fa-info-circle"></i> Visualizar Legenda</a>
                                <?php }else{?>
                                    <a target="_blank" href="https://www.odontobr.com" class="btn btn-sm btn-success"><i class="fas fa-up"></i> Limite alcançado - realizar upgrade?</a>
                                <?php }?>
                            </div>
                            <!-- <small class="text-muted">9 mins</small> -->
                          </div>
                        </div>
                      </div>
                    </div>
                <?php } //foreach?>
            </div>
            <div class="row shadow-md p-3 bg-white rounded">
                <div class="col-sm-12 col-md-6">
                    <div id="paginacao"></div>
                </div>
            </div>      
        <?php
        } else { //if
            echo '<div class="alert alert-warning">Nenhuma imagem encontrada</div>';
        }
        ?>
    </div>
  </div>
</main>

<footer class="text-muted">
  <div class="container">
    <p class="float-right">
      <a href="#navbarHeader">Voltar ao início</a>
    </p>
    <p>Odontopubli - Copyright © 2019</p>

  </div>
</footer>

<script type="text/javascript">
    const totalItens = <?=$qtdeTotal?>;
    const itensPorPagina = <?=$_POST['qtdeItensPagina']?>;
</script>

<script src="js/jquery-3.3.1.slim.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/popper.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/pagination.min.js"></script>
<script src="js/post.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

O problema é que o `ORDER BY` deve vir após o `WHERE` num comando `sql`.

Veja esse pedaço do seu código:

```
$sql = "SELECT * FROM post ORDER BY id DESC";

// a smart code to add all conditions, if any
if ($conditions)
{
    $sql .= " WHERE ".implode(" AND ", $conditions);
}
```

Quando passar pelo `if`, o comando já está com o `ORDER BY`, e vai adicionar o `WHERE` depois dele, o que vai dar erro.

Altere o código para só adicionar o `ORDER BY` depois do `WHERE`. Pode por exemplo remover todos os `ORDER BY` e adicionar aqui:

```
$sql_post = $sql . " ORDER BY id DESC LIMIT ?, ?";
```

Aqui a documentação do comando `select` para enter melhor: [SELECT](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/select.html)

Comment: Muito obrigado mesmo, me ajudou muito!!!